# Need to remove a Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am calling a banner using this;

```
[self.view addSubview:[[AdManager sharedInstance] adMobBanner]];
```

It calls from the AdManager.m file;

```
- (GADRequest *)adMobrequest {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[
                            // TODO: Add your device/simulator test identifiers here. Your device identifier is printed to
                            // the console when the app is launched.
                            GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                            ];
    return request;
}

-(GADBannerView*)adMobBannerWithAdUnitID:(NSString*)adUnitID{
    GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, AdmobBannerHeight)) origin:CGPointMake(0,
                                                                                                                                                                                     [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -AdmobBannerHeight)];
    bannerView.adUnitID = adUnitID;
    NSString *sourceString = [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1];
    // Example: 1   UIKit                               0x00540c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -[]+?.,"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet]];
    [array removeObject:@""];

    bannerView.rootViewController = [array objectAtIndex:3];
    [bannerView loadRequest:[[AdManager sharedInstance] adMobrequest]];

    return bannerView;
}


-(GADBannerView*)adMobBanner{
    GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, AdmobBannerHeight)) origin:CGPointMake(0,
                                                                                                                                                                                     [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -AdmobBannerHeight)];
    bannerView.adUnitID = ADMOB_BANNER_ID;
    NSString *sourceString = [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1];
    // Example: 1   UIKit                               0x00540c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -[]+?.,"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet]];
    [array removeObject:@""];

    bannerView.rootViewController = [array objectAtIndex:3];
    [bannerView loadRequest:[[AdManager sharedInstance] adMobrequest]];

    return bannerView;
}

-(GADBannerView*)adMobBannerWithAdUnitID:(NSString*)adUnitID andOrigin:(CGPoint)origin
{

    GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, AdmobBannerHeight)) origin:origin];
    bannerView.adUnitID = adUnitID;
    NSString *sourceString = [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1];
    // Example: 1   UIKit                               0x00540c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -[]+?.,"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet]];
    [array removeObject:@""];

    bannerView.rootViewController = [array objectAtIndex:3];
    [bannerView loadRequest:[[AdManager sharedInstance] adMobrequest]];

    return bannerView;
}
```

Which is fine, however, I need to stop that view appearing at a certain point (such as a purchase) which I currently have an NSNotification set, upon purchase, to hide the banner, I just can't seem to hide it!

I guess it would be a case of setting the view to remove from superview, but can't seem to find the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to your view before you add it.

```
self.adBanner = [[AdManager sharedInstance] adMobBanner];
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
```

And then later you can use:

```
[self.adBanner removeFromSuperView];
```

Unless I'm missing something that's all you should need to do.

Comment: Indeed, this works perfect! Thanks a lot for your help - marked as complete!